# What are the Scala version-specific source directories in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I am almost sure I read/saw somewhere that latest sbt versions allow me to place Scala-version specific sources in particular directories so they would be picked up depending on `scalaVersion` automatically, without having to fiddle around with `unmanagedSourceDirectories` and creating a source filtering setting. Like

```
src/main/scala/worksInAllVersions.scala
src/main/scala_211???/myTraitForScala211.scala
src/main/scala_210???/myTraitForScala210.scala
```

Is this so? The [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Cross-Build.html) don't mention anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to have been added in [this pull request](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/pull/1799) into sbt 0.13.8. The directories must be named

```
src/main/scala-2.10/
src/main/scala-2.11/
```