# How to organize code for multiple scala versions and differents dependencies

Tags: scala, cross-compiling

I want release library for 2.12 and 2.13 scala version. But it depends on another library, which exist for 2.12 only. For 2.13 I wrote my implementation for `fast` function:

2.12 code looks:

```
import com.dongxiguo.fastring.Fastring.Implicits._ //2.12 only

object Lib {
   val a = fast"hello world"
}
```

2.13 code looks:

```
import mycompat.Implicits._ //2.13 only

object Lib {
   val a = fast"hello world" //my implementation
}
```

So difference - only `import ...` in several files.

I can't understund how to organize code for differents scala version.

Comment: This answer might be helpful: [pick up different source file for different Scala version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23615745/882918) (uses sbt, but if you're using gradle or maven there should be some similar mechanism).

In this approach, you'd need to create `Lib` twice though - one in "2.12" (that would use `com.dongxiguo.fastring`) and one in 2.13 (that would use `mycompat`). And provided that they have exactly the same names and contents, the rest of the app will happily go with it... except probably the faststring in 2.12 and in 2.13 would be different types. and it'll explode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having different imports is problematic, because that means you have different sources (and you need to maintain them). I think providing missing implementation of library in it's own original package will be better solution.

```scala
//main/scala-2.13/com/dongxiguo/fastring/Fastring/Implicits.scala
package com.dongxiguo.fastring.Fastring
object Implicits {
  //your implementation of fast"Something"
}
```

As long as it is in `scala-2.13` folder it will be compiled and used only for scala-2.13.

You need also different dependencies for 2.12 and 2.13 versions:

```scala
libraryDependencies ++= {
  CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
    case Some((2, 12)) => Seq("com.dongxiguo" %% "fastring" % "1.0.0")
    case Some((2, 13)) => Seq()
    case _ => Seq()
  }
}
```

You will have same `Lib` implementation without any change for scala 2.13 and when `fastring` will be released for new scala version You will just remove those parts.

You can also create your own proxy object that will have distinct implementations for 2.12 and 2.13 in `mycompat.Implicits._`.

```scala
//main/scala-2.13/mycompat/Implicits.scala
package com.mycompat
object Implicits { /* proxy to fast"Something" from fastring library */ }

//main/scala-2.12/mycompat/Implicits.scala
package com.mycompat
object Implicits { /* your implementation of fast"Something" */ }
```

This is also good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [lihaoyi](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire/tree/master/autowire/shared/src/main) and [What are the Scala version-specific source directories in sbt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090822/what-are-the-scala-version-specific-source-directories-in-sbt) try something like so

`src/main/scala/example/Hello.scala`:

```
package example

object Hello extends Greeting with App {
  println(greeting)
}
```

`src/main/scala-2.11/example/Greeting.scala`:

```
package example

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello-from-2.11.12"
}
```

`src/main/scala-2.13/example/Greeting.scala`:

```
package example

trait Greeting {
  lazy val greeting: String = "hello-from-2.13.1"
}
```

`build.sbt`:

```
crossScalaVersions := List("2.13.1", "2.11.12")
```

Now `sbt ++2.11.12 run` outputs

```
hello-from-2.11.12
```

whilst `sbt ++2.13.1 run` outputs

```
hello-from-2.13.1
```