# how to tell sbt that which package needs to be compiled based on provided scala version

Tags: scala, sbt, cross-build

I am using sbt cross build my project supports two scala versions `scala-2.12.8` and `scala-2.13.1` and accrodingly i have source code directoroes as

```
src/main/scala_2.12
src/main/test_2.12

src/main/scala_2.13
src/main/test_2.13
```

i looked at the sbt [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html) its not clear from it then i found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615745/pick-up-different-source-file-for-different-scala-version) 
here is my code

```
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <+= (scalaVersion, sourceDirectory in Compile) {
  case (v, dir) if v startsWith "2.12" => dir / "scala_2.12"
  case (v, dir) if v startsWith "2.13" => dir / "scala"
}
```

and  am getting the following error

```
info] Loading project definition from /home/git/testproj/project
/home/git/testproj/build.sbt:54: error: (sbt.SettingKey[String], sbt.SettingKey[java.io.File]) does not take parameters
unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile <+= (scalaVersion, sourceDirectory in Compile) {
                                                                                     ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: If you use `scala-2.12` & `scala-2.13` as the names of your folders, **SBT** will pick them automatically and you do not need to configure nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It's build-in in sbt since 0.13.something for cross compilation:

```
src/main/scala      - shared compiled sources
src/main/scala-2.11 - version-specific compiled sources
src/main/scala-2.12
src/main/scala-2.13

src/test/scala      - shared test sources
src/test/scala-2.11 - version-specific test sources
src/test/scala-2.12
src/test/scala-2.13
```

And for any configuration you created (e.g. `it`, `functional-test`, or whatever you name it) it will be:

```
src/$config/scala               - common code
src/$config/scala-$scalaVersion - version specific code
```

This was described in documentation in [Scala-version specific source directory](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Scala-version+specific+source+directory) section.